# What is the suspend procedure in KDE?

Tags: kde, power-management, suspend

I've been reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76706/what-happens-when-i-press-shut-down-from-the-gui), and I'm wondering what is the procedure for suspending in KDE? Whether to RAM or to disk..

When I click suspend, or close the lid, what gets triggered? What is the chain of events that lead to a certain program getting executed? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

KDE has a device integration framework called Solid.

You can see the API documentation for it here: http://api.kde.org/4.14-api/kdelibs-apidocs/solid/html/index.html

When you click suspend, solid sends a dbus message to Upower (http://upower.freedesktop.org/), the underlying framework, requesting a suspend.

You can simulate a suspend from the command line by doing

```
 qdbus org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement Suspend
```